# Android: Your build is currently configured to use Java 17.0.6 and Gradle 6.1.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm stuck in an error after updating android studio. I have Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1. After update to new version I get this error:

Unsupported Java.
Your build is currently configured to use Java 17.0.6 and Gradle 6.1.1.

Possible solution:

- Upgrade Gradle wrapper to 7.2 version and re-import the project.

Here is my settings in files:

**gradle-wrapper.properties:**

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip`

**build.gradle (app lavel):**

`task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = '7.2' }`

**build.gradle (project lavel):**

`dependencies { classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2" }`

Might be I set wrong version but I'm not able to figure about in which file what changes resolved my problem. Please help me to resolve this issue. Thank you

I try to change version to 7.+ but when ever I tried and import again same issue again and again popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Java 17 requires Gradle 7.3.

Try upgrading your `gradle-wrapper`

Source: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

Answer (score 15):

I was facing same issue and run old projects was being pretty tricky, for testing you can download JDK 11 built in android studio and run old projects.

1. First go to File => Settings => Build, Execution, Deployment => Buiild Tools => Gradle
2. Then select Gradle JDK dropdown and download JDK
3. For me this configuration solved (you can choose the location as you prefer):

[image]

4. After downloading save all and try to sync and build again